# Entity Framework adding association to existing tables

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

If I have a database containing 2 tables one contains stock prices and the other contains information on the various stocks. The table containing the stock prices has a column that contains the stock ID ( the foreign key) which maps to the ID in the stock information table.

How would I set this up in Entity framework, if I look at the .edmx diagram and add a new Association I am unable to specify the key mapping?

Comment: Entity Framework can set this up for you, using the Update Model from Database command. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I'm am not sure how to do the mapping , so the foreign key in one table maps directly to the id of the other table

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713299.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Constraints

Comment: Im sorry I dont get it, I used the code first approach and I already have a foreign key in one of my tables that I want to map to the ID in the other table. This would be a many to many relationship right?

Comment: Or maybe I just need an association, im actually not sure how I should configure this?